# class object also managing a tree structure?

Tags: c++

I'm working on a class hierachy, where an object of a class may contain several objects of the same class.
This would lead to a tree structure:

```
class myClass
{
    myClass *parent;
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<myClass> > childs;

    /*
     * here are some more attributes which describe a myClass object
     * but are not related to the tree structure.
     * std::string name; for example
     */
public:
    //constructors...
    //tree management functions
    //some more members...
}
```

However, after thinking about it for a while, i think this is bad practise.
In this approach, myClass not only needs to have members related to its actual behaviour but also for managing the tree, like searching or inserting childs. This would be a lot of different functionality in one single class.
And, as we are lazy programmers, I don't like to re-invent the wheel.
There are some tree-containers out there, for example the well-known "tree.hpp".
Why not using this container for storing the myClass objects?

Well, problem is, some members ob myClass require access to its parents.
Imagine a member-function like getFullName(), which returns not only the "name"-attribute but a complete path to the actual object(all the parent's names). So this function would need to iterate trough all parent nodes until root is reached.

I'm not sure how i can achieve this using tree.hpp or similar containers.
Does myClass then need to store a pointer to the tree-node which contains it?
But I cannot think of an example where an object has information about the container containing it. An object of a class should not know anything of "being contained". Or am I wrong?
Maybe my first approach (myClass does also the tree management) is even OK?

OK, maybe i should ask a simplier question:
What is a good way to let an object know its own position within a container, e.g. a tree?
What is a good way to let an object access its parent in without storing to much (redundant) information in the object itself?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this is wrong:

```
class myClass
{
    myClass *parent;
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<myClass> > childs;
};
```

Your children should be stored as a vector of `shared_ptr`, and the parent should be a `weak_ptr`.

```
class myClass
{
    std::sweak_ptr<myClass> parent;
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<myClass> > children;
};
```

However, it looks like what you want is a template tree container. So your class should look like this:

```
class myClass
{
    /*
     * here are some more attributes which describe a myClass object
     * but are not related to the tree structure.
     * std::string name; for example
     */
public:
    //constructors...
    //tree management functions
    //some more members...
};
```

And the tree container should be something like this (conceptually):

```
template <typename T>
class tree
{
    std::sweak_ptr<tree> parent;
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<tree> > children;

    T value;
};
```

This tree can be generic and hold different types of objects, including `myClass`.

Comment: Well, it is sufficient that my tree only stores objects of "myClass". But i agree, a template approach would be could practise. Thats why i mentioned tree.hh or similar STL-like containers.
As I stated in my post, I wan't to iterate trough all parents of a node, e.g. for getting a full path to the node (getFullName() would then return "grandparent/parent/node/".
But this requires that myClass knows it is being contained in some kind of data structure and is able to access its parent.
Thats when I can't imagine how to solve this when separating the container implementation from myClass.